# Why is my round function not working properly?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W)), 3) 
FROM STATION;
```

Output:

```
259.68600000
```

Expected output:

```
259.6859
```

Comment: Because you define the number of decimal digits to 3.

Comment: I was actually testing random inputs, point is that why is it still showing those zeros?

Comment: This has to do with the tool/software you are using.

Comment: This highly depends on what **concrete RDBMS** you're using, and what **datatype** those columns are. You've not told us either of these two pieces of information - so we really cannot answer with any degree of certainty....

Comment: You need to see what would be the value without rounding. I believe that the result is rounded, but the tool that visualizes the data for you is not throwing away trailing zeroes (as mentioned above, depending on the data type, the stored value eventually has trailing zeroes). Also, why the expected result should have 4 decimal digits, when you supply 3 as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on the tool.  However, `ROUND()` changes the *value* of a column, but not necessarily the *type*.

I would suggest that you convert to the type you want, which in this case is a decimal"

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)) + ABS(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W)), 3) as DECIMAL(10, 3))
FROM STATION;
```

Your question is unclear whether you want three or four decimal places.  Of course, choose the type appropriate for the number of decimal places that you want.